# Wanted to know if there is any way we can modify existing flux to receive messages at slower rate

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, reactive-kafka

Trying to modify kafka flux which is listening on a kafka topic to accept messages at slow rate. But the blow code is giving exception.

```
public class SampleConsumer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleConsumer.class.getName());

    private static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "localhost:9092";
    boolean slow = false;
    private static final String TOPIC = "demo-topic";

    private final ReceiverOptions<Integer, String> receiverOptions;
    private final DateTimeFormatter dateFormat;

    public SampleConsumer(String bootstrapServers) {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "sample-consumer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "sample-group");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create(props);
        dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss:SSS z dd MMM yyyy");
    }

    public void consumeMessages(String topic, CountDownLatch latch) {

        ReceiverOptions<Integer, String> options = receiverOptions.subscription(Collections.singleton(topic))
                .addAssignListener(partitions -> log.debug("onPartitionsAssigned {}", partitions))
                .addRevokeListener(partitions -> log.debug("onPartitionsRevoked {}", partitions));
        Flux<ReceiverRecord<Integer, String>> kafkaFlux = KafkaReceiver.create(options).receive();
        
        Disposable disposable = kafkaFlux.doOnNext(record -> System.out.println("Received message: value="+
                record.value()) )
        .subscribe(record -> {
            ReceiverOffset offset = record.receiverOffset();
            offset.acknowledge();
            
        });
        
        if(slow) // logic has been implemented for this
{
            disposable.dispose();
            
            disposable = kafkaFlux.take(1, true).doOnNext(record -> System.out.println("Received slow message: value="+
                    record.value()) )
            .subscribe(record -> {
                ReceiverOffset offset = record.receiverOffset();
                offset.acknowledge();
                
            });
        }
        
        
    }}
```

Exception:
Caused by reactor.core.Exceptions$StaticRejectedExecutionException : Scheduler unavailable

Wanted to know if there is any way we can modify existing flux to receive messages at slower rate